# Rails Listener in marker on Gmaps4rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, listener, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm trying do add a listener in my markers but doesn't work
in my view i have the `BuildMap(<%= @hash.to_json %>);`
my controller is

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(gon.transmitters) do |transmitter, marker|
    marker.lat transmitter.latitude
    marker.lng transmitter.longitude
    marker.json({ :id => "trm", :data => transmitter.id , :img => "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/B/1/E/y/r/marker-pin-google.svg"})
end
```

and in my js.coffee

```
@buildMap = (markers) ->
  handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
  handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
    for marker in markers
      google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', ->
        alert "hello" 
        true
      true
```

What i am doing wrong?
thanks in advance
edit: [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) where are you?!? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`marker` is a proxy object, simply replace:

```
google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', ->
```

with:

```
google.maps.event.addListener marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', ->
```

Comment: No idea for my part...there aren't some errors in the console i really don't know what i have to do

Comment: Fixed. I had one issue with Rails cache deleting tmp folder and restarting server all works. Many Thanks!

Comment: Many Many Many Many Many Many  thanx to apneadiving,this answer is very very useful for me,i lost my four days for this issue.